# Manage Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames with Az PowerShell module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services

I have a classic Compute resource. I need to move some old deployment code that used Azure.Service module to Az and I was wondering, is there a way to manage that with Az or something up to date?
I have to upload some .cspkg and some .cscfg files. There is more to it, but basically, this was done using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/new-azuredeployment?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) cmdlet and the related ones, Set, Get etc.

I used Az.Resources' cmdlet New-AzResource to create it:

```
New-AzResource `
    -Location 'location' `
    -ResourceGroupName 'rgName' `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames' `
    -ResourceName 'rName' `
    -ApiVersion '2018-06-01'
```

What cmdlets could I use to manage this resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could use [`Az.CloudService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/?view=azps-5.5.0#cloudservice) module commands, to upload some .cspkg and some .cscfg files, use [`New-AzCloudService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/new-azcloudservice?view=azps-5.5.0) with parameters `-PackageUrl` and `-ConfigurationUrl`(or `-Configuration`).

The command `New-AzCloudService` can `Create or update a cloud service`, i.e. `New`, `Set` operations, to do `Get` operation, use [`Get-AzCloudService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/get-azcloudservice?view=azps-5.5.0) command.

Anyway, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/?view=azps-5.5.0#cloudservice) for all the commands to manage `Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames` i.e. `Cloud service`, use them depends on your requirement.

**Update:**

In this case, looks you could not migrate your commands to `Az` module, `Az.CloudService` is for the new [**Cloud Service(extended support)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/overview) which is ARM(Azure Resource Manager) based, and it is in the preview version, see [Deploy a Cloud Service (extended support) using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-powershell), some features might not be supported, I think the error was caused by this.

[image]

What you are using is **Cloud Service(classic)**, it is ASM(Azure Service Management) based, the new `Az` module is just for ARM resources.

So in your case, you may need to continue to use `Azure.Service` module, or you can migrate the ASM to ARM i.e. `Cloud Service(classic)` to `Cloud Service(extended support)`, see [`Migration to Azure Resource Manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/overview#migration-to-azure-resource-manager), but not recommend you to use it in the production environment as it is in preview.

Comment: For some reason I get this error `New-AzCloudService : The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Compute' for api version '2020-10-01-preview'.`

Comment: @Vivere Sorry for the oversight, please see my update.

Comment: I think it's okay to update to Cloud Service(extended support) since they mention `Cloud Services (extended support) will primarily maintain feature parity with Cloud Services (classic)`. For that though, I wanted to create this resource and see if and how it works, but neither creating a new one works. I didn't try to update the existing one, I just wanted to create a new one and I got that error. I opened an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14385 . If you have any insights into it please let me know, but as far as the original question goes, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Vivere You can try to create it in the portal, looks it will work, https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgyxu.png.

Comment: It might and should work in the portal, but I need to create scripts to automate this process. Hopefully, I will get it to work soon in the powershell aswell

Comment: @Vivere I think it maybe a bug as it is just in preview, I can also reproduce your issue with a simple line `New-AzCloudService -Name xxx -ResourceGroupName xxx -Location eastus `, and per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2020-10-01-preview/cloudservices), the api version should be correct.